# T-SQL. Значение поля использовать как имя столбца подзапроса/JOIN-а

Tags: sql-server

Вопрос такой.
Условное, если есть таблица:

```
@access
id | field | value
```

Нужно применить значения из неё к запросу

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table tbl
    JOIN @access ac ON tbl[ac.field] = ac.value
```

Такое возможно реализовать без текстовых экзекьютов?

Comment: невозможно. скорее всего требуется по другому спроектировать БД

Comment: Если список значений `ac.field` статический - можно построить соотв. CASE.

Comment: динамическим sql можно